# Problem to concatenate AlpineJS x-text and HREF property

Tags: javascript, href, alpine.js

I have a Datatable table being fed by AlpineJS:

```
<template x-for = "user in users": key = "user.Id">
```

In x-for, I have the value of user.Id that I can list in a SPAN field, with the instruction x-text:

```
<span id = "user.Id" class = "text-gray-700 px-6 py-3 flex items-center" x-text = "user.Id"> </span>
```

I need to concatenate the value of user.Id at the end of my HREF property, which will call a route on the backend to inactivate a record:

Directly, trying to set the HREF + user.Id property, it didn't work, so I thought about the following:

```
<script>
   var uid = document.getElementById ("user.Id");
   console.log ('uid value:' + uid.InnerText);
   var link = document.getElementById ("link");
   link.setAttribute ('href', 'http://api-paulinhomonteiro-com.umbler.net/cli/delete/<%= token%> /' + uid.innertText)
</script>
```

It worked very well by setting the property dynamically but the variable arrives as undefined.

How could I solve this? I just discovered AlpineJS and I can't go any further. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this with Alpine you need to use x-bind:

```html
<span 
  id = "user.Id"
  x-bind:href="'http://api-paulinhomonteiro-com.umbler.net/cli/delete/' + user.Id"
  class = "text-gray-700 px-6 py-3 flex items-center" 
  x-text = "user.Id"> </span>
```

Comment: Great!!!!!! It´s so simply... 

@Hugo, I'm gratefull so much... 

I let it more simply as possible:

<code>
    <td class="border-dashed border-t border-gray-200 Acao">
        <a x-bind:href="'http://api-paulinhomonteiro-com.umbler.net/cli/delete/<%=token%>/' + 
        user.Id">Apagar                     
         </a>                             
     </td>
</code>

Can you talk mora about x-bind? Can i set any property for any element by this method?

AlpineJS is the great solution for small reactive aplications. I love it.